# What is the precise name of this quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

Picture

[image]

I was thinking about half rectangle but there must be better name for it. 
You can assume r1r2 and r3r4 are not equal.

What is the name of this geometric shape?

Comment: a trapezoid. (trusting that the vertical lines are parallel)

Comment: It's a Trapezoid.

Comment: truncated triangle

Comment: @lulu: Vertical lines are always parallel (if we neglect the curvature of the earth) :-)

Comment: @joriki Point taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trapezoid or trapezium. (Assuming that the two opposite lines are parellel). 
If not, then it will be a normal (convex) quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in the comments, this is a trapezoid, assuming that $\overline{r_1r_4}$ and $\overline{r_2r_3}$ are parallel.

Comment: What if those are not parallel?

Comment: @Masi: Then I don't see anything special about it -- then it's just a generic quadrilateral. If you want a special name for it, you need to specify what its special properties are that not every quadrilateral has.

Comment: @Masi: If those are not parallel, we can call it a convex quadrilateral.

Comment: Furthermore, since the longer base edge has two acute angles, we can call this an *acute* trapezoid.

Comment: A tetragon if you want to put it Greek.